# Delete a specific file from VSTS git history

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am using azure devops Git repository.

I have a specific file which needs to be deleted from all the previous commits(history) made to the branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this operation cannot be implemented by rest api or ui in Azure devops.

As one contributor mentioned in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432137/how-do-i-delete-a-file-from-the-git-commit-history-from-every-branch-locally-and): Each commit in a git repository builds upon previous commits and depends upon the contents of that commit. So rewriting even one commit with a tiny change somewhere in the history means changes to all the commits that come after it.  So "Delete a specific file from VSTS git history"
this operation is not very reasonable

If you really want to do this, you can try the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) tool.For details please refer to the case mentioned in the comment.